# Development (multi)site indexed - recommendations to redirect 301 to correct url?

Tags: multisite, redirect

Have just finished working on a dev site and the live site has been launched (on a different server/url) - unfortunately, Google bots were very efficient and have inadvertently indexed the dev site (which became 'open/live' during the last few days of development for testing purposes)

I have now archived the site, but if visitors reach it, all they receive is a 'suspended' message - so I was wondering how best to 'redirect' users to the new/correct url and server using multisite?

e.g. would it be best to use a plugin like Redirection and direct all traffic away? Or to leave it as archived so 'suspended'?  And would it be advisable to use Google's Remove URL tool?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both sites using the same permalink structure?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) to your dev site’s `.htaccess` to tell Google the canonical addresses are on the new site:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent (.*) http://new.example.com$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Can I just clarify that it should be placed in the multisite .htaccess file?  (Apologies for not being clear that the dev site was part of a multisite)